# Sharing Ruby on Rails session cookie with NodeJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, session-cookies

I would like decode the RoR session cookie from within my NodeJS application. Before I start digging into the Ruby source I wanted to see if anyone already has a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: It may be hard with Rails 4 since cookies are encrypted.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3 session cookies. From what I see they are only signed.

Source: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb

Comment: Yes, but at some point you may wish to migrate and then it will be a problem. Wouldn't it make more sense to access session server side?